# Marketplace error d000f001

Tags: store, 7.8, nokia-lumia-610

I am using a Nokia Lumia 610 running Windows Phone 7.8 and I can't download apps from the marketplace. I get an error saying "We can't complete your request now try again later". Then it shows error d000f001. How can I fix this?

Comment: I believe Window Phone 7.8 went out of support back in 2014 - I believe the store was closed around this time, too - I'll see if I can find a more definitive source than my memory, and update later :)

Comment: some user at Microsoft answers website said that he he had contacted Microsoft support a week back and they told him that unfortunately the support has ended for WP7.8 in terms of the ability of downloading apps from the store. Damn you Microsoft