# Windows Live ID Account Login Problem

Tags: microsoft-account, 7.8

I have an HTC HD7 which had been sitting in my drawer for 4 years, it's running Windows Phone 7.8 and I want to install some apps on it through the Marketplace app but it requires me to sign in with a Microsoft Windows Live ID account, but I can't sign-in on it, did Microsoft drop the servers?

When I enter my outlook email and password and tap "sign in" it says `Connecting to Windows Live...` on the status bar and after less than a minute I get this error:

> **Can't connect**
>
> We're hacing a problem connecting to Windows Live. Make
> sure you have good reception, If you do, the problem may be on the
> other end. Wait a little wile and try again.

Marketplace app can be opened and it shows apps and games but I need to be signed-in with a Windows Live ID account to download from it. Is there any workaround or hack or solution so I can install some apps through the Marketplace or with Zune?

**Edit:** I've got a Dynamics 2.2 ROM on my phone which means my phone is fully unlocked, I can deploy apps etc.. Is there any hack to download apps from the Marketplace? (On phone or from the computer.)

[This article shows that WP7.8 should still receive updates until 2019.](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-78-mainstream-support-ends-september-9?utm_source=wpc&utm_medium=twitter)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [article](https://www.windowscentral.com/windows-phone-78-mainstream-support-ends-september-9) you linked to is from 2014 and isn't completely accurate anymore.

According to Microsoft's Lifecycle Policy, [support for WP 7.8](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/lifecycle/search?alpha=Windows%20Phone%207.8) ended on 14 October 2014, with no 5-year extended support promised.

The [official WP7 support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/11696/windows-phone-7) also says that the OS is no longer supported and, crucially, "services and functionality ... will be discontinued over time". A quick search online shows that people have been reporting issues with the Marketplace since late 2017 (e.g. [[1]](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/16425/1401), [[2]](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/7sg5jt/windows_phone_78_marketplace_not_working), [[3]](https://www.reddit.com/r/windowsphone/comments/7ol1ar/windows_phone_7_marketplace_error_d000f001), [[4]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdwindows-mdaccount-mdversionwp7/windows-phone-7578-marketplace-not-working/688275a2-71e1-4237-b71d-317db4d0b8f8), [[5]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdapps-mdlumia800/windows-phone-78-error-d000f001/1a1a90b3-904f-4ef2-beba-7e950c34e9a3)).

If Microsoft have finally taken down the necessary back-end services for the WP7 Marketplace, I doubt there's any hack or workaround you can perform on your device to fix this. Best to accept the device is basically a paperweight and move on.

Comment: Thanks for writing this answer, could you kindly take a look at my edit in question?

Comment: @Shayan Sorry, I've never used 7.8 myself, so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: No probs! I think I can use it as a paperweight now xD

Comment: it's kinda confusing since the marketplace itself is up, so if you're logged in you can download stuff I guess. and people are reporting it occasionally working.